# Navbar right falling below brand

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I'm trying to create a navbar with two links generated in Ruby on Rails. For now, pretty much trying to make the brand on the left and either log in/sign up or log out/post ad on the right. However, my right nav bar is falling below on a new line. Like the width of the navbar isn't large enough to hold all the items.

Here is a screenshot of what I am describing....

[image]

The right navbar is falling below the brand.

index.html.erb

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SHIP LIST</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <% if user_signed_in?%>
      <li><a href="#"><%= link_to 'post ad', new_listing_path %></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><%= link_to 'log out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
      <% else %>
      <li><a href="#"><%= link_to 'sign up', new_user_registration_path %></li>
      <li><a href="#"><%= link_to 'log in', new_user_session_path %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

My css is as follows, I did have to make changes with it so the alerts for Devise show below the navbar, so that may be causing it. I don't think it is but.

```
  body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }

.alert-box {
  color:#555;
  border-radius:10px;
  font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:11px;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 36px;
  margin:10px;
  span {
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
  }
}
.danger {
    background:#ffecec url('images/error.png') no-repeat 10px 50%;
    border:1px solid #f5aca6;
}
.success {
    background:#e9ffd9 url('images/success.png') no-repeat 10px 50%;
    border:1px solid #a6ca8a;
}
.warning {
    background:#fff8c4 url('images/warning.png') no-repeat 10px 50%;
    border:1px solid #f2c779;
}
.notice {
    background:#e3f7fc url('images/notice.png') no-repeat 10px 50%;
    border:1px solid #8ed9f6;
}
```

Comment: Hard to determine what's actually going on without a working example but try putting ul.nav navbar-nav navbar-right inside of div.navbar-header

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, I'll try to rip it out into just like a static barebones HTML/CSS without the Rails stuff, see if that is the cause in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following code pertaining to the right nav bar...

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <% if user_signed_in?%>
  <li><a href="#"><%= link_to 'post ad', new_listing_path %></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><%= link_to 'log out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
  <% else %>
  <li><a href="#"><%= link_to 'sign up', new_user_registration_path %></li>
  <li><a href="#"><%= link_to 'log in', new_user_session_path %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Remove the link tags like so...

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <% if user_signed_in?%>
  <li><%= link_to 'post ad', new_listing_path %></a></li>
  <li><%= link_to 'log out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
  <% else %>
  <li><%= link_to 'sign up', new_user_registration_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to 'log in', new_user_session_path %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Rails will automatically generate them for you, so you don't need to add them in like that manually. It was overflowing as it was trying to add in four links instead of two. Nothing to do with the Devise gem, that is being generated in the body of the HTML page.